# Laravel relationships between my models

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel, model

I have three tables:

> users

This table contains the usual user data. ID, email, password, username etc.

> teams

[Image of my teams table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEyRg.png)

> members

[Image of my members table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b9xH.png)

My members table is used to keep track of which users are part of which teams.

What I'm trying to create is a route which when visited, displays all the teams that user is currently a part of.

This is what I've tried:

> Team.php

```
<?php

namespace EG;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Team extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'teams';

    public function members()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Member');
    }
}
```

> Member.php

```
<?php

namespace EG;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Member extends Model
{

    protected $table = 'members';

    public function teams()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('Team');
    }
}
```

> routes.php

```
Route::get('/test', function () {
    $member = EG\Member::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get();
    $teams = $member->teams;
    foreach($teams as $team) {
        echo $team->team_name."<br>";
    }
});
```

I'm getting this error when I visit /test:

> ErrorException in routes.php line 94:
>   Undefined property: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::$teams

Just so you guys can better understand what I'm trying to create, here is how I would do it procedurally:

```
$sql = “SELECT team_id FROM members WHERE user_id = ‘“.Auth::user()->id.”';”;
$result = mysqli_querry($conn, $sql);
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $sql = “SELECT * FROM teams WHERE id = ‘“.$row[’team_id'].”';”;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    while ($team = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
        echo $team[’team_name’].”<br>”;
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`->get()` method returns a collection.

If you need a single model use the `->first()` method:

```
$member = EG\Member::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->first();
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have worked. I'm now getting an error saying that class 'Team' doesn't exist. I'm assuming it's a problem with this line in Member.php: return $this->belongsTo('Team');

Comment: I've fixed that, I'm now getting this error: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: to fix the first error: `return $this->belongsTo('App\Team');` . Try this to fix the most recent error: `$teams = $member->teams()->get()`

Comment: Okay I have no errors now but the page is just blank

Comment: The $member->teams()->get(); isn't actually returning any data. Do I need to define the foreign keys in my hasMany and belongsTo?

Comment: You need foreign keys in the tables, or you probably dont have any related data.

Comment: I have the data. How should I set the foreign keys in my model functions?

Comment: You can pass the foreign key as the second parameter `return $this->belongsTo('App\Team', 'foreign_key');`

Comment: What's the foreign_key needed in my case?